# Good way to find / replace using regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have an value that is not being read by our OCR program correctly. It's predicable so I would like to use a find/replace in regex (because this is how we are already extracting the data).

We get the named group like this: `(?<Foo>.*?)`

I would like to replace 'N1123456' with 'NY123456'. We know that we expect NY when we are getting N1.

What can I try to get this done in the same regular expression?

Edit: `(?<Foo>.*?)`

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Always 6 digits -- no more, no less -- *required* after the "NY"? Word boundary at the start and the end?

Comment: `(?.*?)` is a syntax error...

Comment: @Dalorzo  I'm using vb.net. The regular expressions are stored in the web.config of the application; we need to tweak them every once in a while when we get artifacts in the OCR. This is why I'd like to do the replace in the regex itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
 Dim str = Regex.Replace("N1123456", @"\bN1(\d+)", "NY$1");
```

The Expression to find the text is **N1** followed by numbers like : `\bN1(\d+)`.

The numbers belongs to the group(1) I would like to preserve and attach to **NY** during replacing: `NY$1`

Comment: This one works the best for what I need. This is similar to what Lucas posted but I like this for what I need since I could have a variable number of digits in the future.

Comment: Final solution: ^(?<Foo>\bN1(?<Bar>\d+)).name:(?<FirstName>.*?).last:(?<LastName>.*?)$ Replacment: NY${Bar}

Answer (score 1):

Make groups of non digits and digits and add `Y` after non digit group.

```
(\D+)(\d+)
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rI6yA4/17)

Enclose it inside `\b` or  `^` and `$` for better precision.

---

Sample code:

PHP:

```
$re = ""(\\D+)(\\d+)"";
$str = "N1123456";
$subst = '$1Y$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

Python:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(\D+)(\d+)')
test_str = u"N1123456"
subst = u"$1Y$2"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Java:

```
System.out.println("N1123456".replaceAll("(\\D+)(\\d+)","$1Y$2"));
```

Comment: This is close but not exactly what I need to look for N1.

Comment: I provided you a global solution. I thought you are using it just for an example. You can change it easily. Not a big change `(N1)(\d+)`

Comment: what is `Foo` in your example? What are you doing with `Foo`?

Comment: since you haven't mentioned language hence I provided for all but the concept is same in all the language in .net as well and that is `$`

Comment: We do something like this to get named groups:

^(?<Foo>.*?).name:(?<FirstName>.*?).last:(?<LastName>.*?)$

Input: N1123456 name:john last:smith

Comment: Final solution: ^(?<Foo>\bN1(?<Bar>\d+)).name:(?<FirstName>.*?).last:(?<LastName>.*?)$      Replacment: NY${Bar}

Answer (score 1):

If you expect `N1` to be always followed by 6 digits, then you can do this:

Replace this: `\bN1(\d{6})\b` with this: `NY$1`.

This will replace any `N1` followed by 6 digits with `NY`.

Comment: This one works for what I need since I need to find the string 'N1' first before replacing.